# Dimension of vector space of real numbers over rational number field

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that dimension  of $\mathbb{R} $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $ is infinite. What can i say about the cardinality of its basis mean whether  it is countable or uncountable. Can we find exact basis for that.

Comment: The dimension is the cardinality of $\Bbb R$. You can't explicitly write a basis down though.

Comment: How to show that basis is uncountable

Comment: If a basis were countable then $\Bbb R$ would be countable.

Comment: Is there any uncountable  subset of real numbers which is linearly  independent?

Comment: Yes, linearly independent over the rationals

Answer (score 7):

Note that if $(e_i)_{i \in I}\subset \Bbb R$, with $I$ countable, then: $${\rm span}_{\Bbb Q}((e_i)_{i \in I}) = \left\{ \sum_{i \in F}\alpha_ie_i \mid \alpha_i \in \Bbb Q,~F \subset I \text{ finite} \right\}$$is countable, so ${\rm span}_{\Bbb Q}((e_i)_{i \in I}) \neq \Bbb R$. So $I$ must be uncountable if it is to span whole $\Bbb R$.