# Real numbers as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's consider the real numbers as a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear space and denote it by $\mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. It was proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312801/dimension-of-vector-space-of-real-numbers-over-rational-number-field) that $\dim  \mathbb{R}_{\mathbb{Q}} > \aleph_0$. I suspect that the dimension is actually $\mathfrak c$. But how could we prove it's really $\mathfrak c$ ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67751

Comment: @Watson Which answer there are you talking about?

Comment: If $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal then a set of cardinality $\kappa$ has only $\kappa$ finite subsets...

Comment: @David : I edited the link. It is Leon's answer, for instance.

Comment: @The answer by Leon in the purported duplicate seems unnecessarily complicated, and the other answers answer a different question than this one.

Comment: @David : I agree. But [Arturo Magidin](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6247) added a simple argument in his answer.

Comment: @Watson He states that the dimension is uncountable, not that it is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @David : is my following argument correct? A $\Bbb Q$-basis $B \subset \Bbb R$ has cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0} = |\Bbb R|$. Since $B$ is not countable, we get $|B|>\aleph_0$. Assuming the continuum hypothesis, we have $|B|=2^{\aleph_0}$. Is it necessary to use to continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @Alphonse The argument is correct if you assume the continuum hypothesis. But that's unnecessary. A vector space over a countably infinite field has the same cardinality as its basis.

Comment: @David : yes, I see. If $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over a countably infinite field $k$ then $V \cong k^{(J)}$ where $J$ is an infinite set. Then $$|V|=|k^{(J)}|=\left| \bigsqcup\limits_{I \in \mathcal P} k^I \right| = |\mathcal P| \cdot |k| = |\mathcal P| = |J|$$ where $\mathcal P$ denotes the collection of finite subsets of $J$.

Comment: @Alphonse Right, although in your argument some of those inequalities should at first be written as inequalities. Then apply Cantor-Bernstein.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583601